# Caman.js: get parent object

Tags: javascript, canvas, camanjs

Refering to JS Caman library: http://camanjs.com

I want to get the parent element containing the canvas and `$().fadeIn(500);` after the image has been processed.

The `<canvas>` object is inside a `<div>`

From the authors': http://camanjs.com/guides/#AdvancedUsage

```
Caman.Event.listen("processComplete", function (job) {
  console.log("Finished:", job.name);
  alert('parent element:' + $(this).parent().prop('tagName') );
});
```

The event is triggered after each canvas process is finished. However I can't get the parent element, it returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Wouldn't something like `element.parentNode` work? you could set `element` using a number of selectors, depending on what it is

Comment: still 'undefined'. The Caman library works perfectly. It is a gallery of images. Each image (canvas) has a parent div which I'm trying to fade in after the canvas is done processing. But the canva's parent is always 'undefined', with or without jquery.

Comment: no i'm sure it does; that was just my first thought. hmm. What do you get if you were to log `this` out?

Comment: ´this´ returns a canvas object, which is not mine ('cause mine have ids). So it probably creates a virtual canvas outside the document.

Comment: Gotcha; is this a situation where you could hard-code in the dom-accessor for that canvas? or does this need to find the parent node regardless?

Comment: Or if the `canvas` object that caman returns has anything on it that you could use to access the parent, you could potentially go that route, too

Comment: Either way. I just want to get to the parent DIV to fade it in ´.fadeIn()´. the problem is that Caman won't give me access to that div from the event listener "processComplete".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68575/discussion-between-markthethomas-and-azevedo).

Answer (score 0):

After trying and trying....

```
Caman.Event.listen("processComplete", function (job, myObj=$("#myParentDiv")) {
  console.log("Finished:", job.name);
  alert('parent element:' + $(myObj).prop('tagName') );
});
```

I just added an extra parameter (myObj) being the parent object, so it can be referenced from inside the function.